# How to turn off console.info messages from Nuxt server?

Tags: vue.js, pycharm, nuxt.js

I am running tests and receive unnecessary `console.info` texts in terminal, I would like to get rid of:

```
  console.info
    Download the Vue Devtools extension for a better development experience:
    https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools

      at node_modules/vue/dist/vue.common.dev.js:9051:47

  console.info
    You are running Vue in development mode.
    Make sure to turn on production mode when deploying for production.
    See more tips at https://vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html

      at node_modules/vue/dist/vue.common.dev.js:9060:45
```

```js
const { Nuxt } = require('nuxt')
const nuxtConfig = require('../../../../nuxt.config.js')

let nuxt = null

beforeAll(async () => {
  nuxt = new Nuxt({
    ...nuxtConfig,
    buildDir: constants.buildDir
  })

  await nuxt.server.listen(constants.port, 'localhost')
}, 300000)
```

I've tried to put vue.config silent property in various places in code above, but also into `nuxt.config.js`, but I got no luck doing so. I've tried this snippet: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-vue-config/

```js
export default {
  vue: {
    config: {
      productionTip: true,
      devtools: false
    }
  }
}
```

How to turn off `console.info` messages?

Answer (score 0):

You could right click on the message in your devtools console and go with `Hide messages from vue.runtime.esm.js`. It will hide it from your console thanks to a filter. Do not solves the real problem, but a nice and quick fix.

Pretty much as here: https://superuser.com/a/995289/850722

Comment: Unfortunately no such option in Jetbrains (PyCharm). Thanks anyway for suggestion..